# BindingSource attached to ListBox.DataSource doesn't update ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I have a listbox attached to a binding source. In the designer I've got a binding source fileConfigurationBindingSource. I have a fileConfigurationsListBox that displays these with displaymember "Name" and DataSource fileConfigurationBindingSource.

During initialization I set the FileConfigurationBindingSource to a Linq table of objects:

```
   public FileUploadConfiguration() {
        InitializeComponent();

        //load from our database (FileConfigurations is a Table<FileCOnfiguration> that has "Name" property)
        //This collection was automatically generated by Linq to SQL
        fileConfigurationBindingSource.DataSource = ObjectStore.DataContext.FileConfigurations;
        ...
   }
```

This functions fine if there are objects in the database. I change the name property, the list updates when that property is changed in the underlying data.

However, if I add a new item the listbox doesn't update.

```
   private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //create a new one
        ObjectStore.CreateFileConfiguration();
   }
```

This didn't work, I had a look on the internet and though I might need this method adding:

```
   private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //create a new one
        ObjectStore.CreateFileConfiguration();
        fileConfigurationBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
   }
```

But that did nothing either. I've tried nulling the listbox.datasource and resetting it. I've tried the listbox.refresh(), update(), everything I can think of.

When I look into the data source objects, it looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/GgMBhUz.png]

I can see the two objects in the bindingSource's datasources, but the actual fileConfigurationBindingSource's count is zero, and so is the fileConfigurationsListBox.

Does anyone know why these changes aren't filtering down to the items or at least the bindingsource?